# Itext 7 Split Paragraph

Tags: java, itext, itext7

How can I split a given paragraph to 2 paragraphs, due to that it fits only partial into canvas. After split, I would like to add the first part into canvas and the second to a new canvas.

```
public Paragraph addParagraphToPage(PdfDocument pdfDocument, int pageNum, Rectangle rectangle, Paragraph p) 
{
    PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(pageNum);        
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamAfter(), page.getResources(), pdfDocument);        
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDocument, rectangle);

    ParagraphRenderer currentRenderer = (ParagraphRenderer) p.createRendererSubTree();      
    currentRenderer.setParent(canvas.getRenderer());    
    result = currentRenderer.layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(pageNum, rectangle)));

    ArrayList<Paragraph> paragraphs = new ArrayList<Paragraph>();
    if (result.getStatus() != LayoutResult.FULL)
    {           
        paragraphs = ????? // getNextParagraph(paragraphs, result, pageNum, rectangle, canvas);

        if(paragraphs.size() == 2)
        {
            canvas.add( paragraphs.get(0));
            return paragraphs.get(1);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Share your code, be more explicit..

Comment: I would be glad, if someone could help me.

Comment: It would be ok, wait for a while

Comment: Where exactly shall ite be split?

Comment: @mkl First part: depends on which part of the paragraph fits into canvas (getSplitRenderer). Second part: is the rest of the paragraph (getOverflowRenderer)

Comment: A regular `DocumentRenderer` would do that for your automatically, wouldn't it? And if you need to customize the column sizes, the `ColumnDocumentRenderer` implementation should show a way...

Comment: @mkl Here we have the difference that the paragraph will be added in a canvas and not in a Document. ColumnDocumentRenderer does not work. The second part of the paragraph after the split will be added somewhere into the next page.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using a `PdfCanvas` instead of just adding the `Paragraph` to the `Document` and letting the regular rendering framework take care of the splitting?

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck  The reason is that the paragraph will be printed after Stream, in a given pdfDocument, in a given pageNum, in a given rectagnle. If there is not enough space, then the paragraph has to be splitted and the second part to be printed into the next page. PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamAfter(), page.getResources(), pdfDocument);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct in general and layout in iText7 is flexible enough to allow you to do required thing in an easy manner. The only thing I see that is not very clear is that `Paragraph` is actually an element that cannot split itself and no classes in layout framework facilitate element splitting. You could do it manually, but there is no need to. Instead you should work with `IRenderer`, and `ParagraphRenderer` in particular, directly.

`IRenderer` can split itself as a result of `layout` operation and represents the necessary portion of data only compared to the `Paragraph` which contains full data.

You can add an `IRenderer` to the `CanvasRenderer`:

```
canvas.getRenderer().addChild(rendererToAdd.setParent(canvas.getRenderer()));
```

And you can access the partial renderers (the portion that fit the passed area and overflow part) from `LayoutResult#getSplitRenderer()` and `LayoutResult#getOverflowRenderer()`.

In general, your code can be adapted like follows:

```
public ParagraphRenderer addParagraphToPage(PdfDocument pdfDocument, int pageNum, Rectangle rectangle, ParagraphRenderer renderer) {
    PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(pageNum);
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamAfter(), page.getResources(), pdfDocument);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(pdfCanvas, pdfDocument, rectangle);

    renderer.setParent(canvas.getRenderer());
    LayoutResult result = renderer.layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(pageNum, rectangle)));

    IRenderer rendererToAdd = result.getStatus() == LayoutResult.FULL ? renderer : result.getSplitRenderer();

    canvas.getRenderer().addChild(rendererToAdd.setParent(canvas.getRenderer()));

    return result.getStatus() != LayoutResult.FULL ? (ParagraphRenderer) result.getOverflowRenderer() : null;
}
```

And then for adding paragraph to sequential pages until all the content is placed you basically need only two lines of code:

```
ParagraphRenderer renderer = (ParagraphRenderer) p.createRendererSubTree();
while ((renderer = addParagraphToPage(pdfDocument, pageNum++, rectangle, renderer)) != null);
```

Comment: How would you just capture the text?  My first page is split in thirds with the 1st and 3rd section static elements.  I need the second section overflow to carry over to the second page as a continuation sheet.